# Best way to control page titles on a large website in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a fairly large website with several master pages.  Right now the titles are being controlled by Session variables in individual pages and set by the master page.  The code is bad and needs to be redone.  With the current system, since the master page is executed last, we can't completely overwrite the page title when needed from the page.  What is the best way to create breadcrumbed page titles across a large site in ASP.NET with several master pages, without using Sessions variables?  Session variables are bad for page titles mmmkkayy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `Page.Header.Title` property will set the page title, even with a masterpage.

Comment: understood, but we want our page titles breadcrumbed also without going to every single individual page setting the breadcrumb ourself.  we need a system here.

Comment: Then you will need to build it, but you can. It really depends on what you are after as far as hierarchy. You could read the folder structure and page name and dynamically set it on each content page.